# How to run Sencha app on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have created an app using the below Sencha command in the command line as below

```
sencha app create mysenchaApp /path/to/www/mysenchaApp
```

This given me as below

```
Code:

[INFO] Created file C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\.senchasdk
[INFO] Created file C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\index.html
[INFO] Created file C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\app.js
[INFO] Created file C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\packager.json
[INFO] Created file C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\app.json
[INFO] Created file C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\app\view\Main.js
[INFO] Copied dir: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\sdk\src
[INFO] Copied dir: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\sdk\resources
[INFO] Copied dir: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\resources\icons
[INFO] Copied dir: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\resources\loading
[INFO] Copied dir: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\sdk\command
[INFO] Copied file: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\sdk\microloader\development.js
[INFO] Copied file: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\sdk\microloader\testing.js
[INFO] Copied file: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\sdk\microloader\production.js
[INFO] Copied file: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\sdk\version.txt
[INFO] Copied file: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\sdk\sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Copied file: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\sdk\sencha-touch-all.js
[INFO] Created file C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\resources\sass\app.scss
[INFO] Created file C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\resources\sass\config.rb
[INFO] Copied file: C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\resources\css\app.css
```

Then I modified the packager.json file as below to get it run on emulator:

```
Code:

/**
     * @cfg {String} applicationName
     * @required
     * This is the name of your application, which is displayed on the  device when the app is installed. On IOS, this should match
     * the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning Portal.
     */
    "applicationName":"My Application",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} applicationId
     * This is the name namespace for your application. On IOS, this  should match the name of your application in the Apple Provisioning  Portal.
     */
    "applicationId":"com.mycompany.myAppID",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} versionString
     * @required
     * This is the version of your application.
     */
    "versionString":"1.0",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} iconName
     * This is file name of your icon. This should be in the same directory of this configuration file.
     *
     * For iOS, please refer to their documentation about icon sizes:
     * https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html
     *
     * For Android, please refer to the Google Launcher icons guide:
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html
     */
    "iconName":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} inputPath
     * @required
     * This is location of your Sencha Touch 2 application, relative to this configuration file.
     */
    "inputPath":"build/native",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} outputPath
     * @required
     * This is where the built application file with be saved.
     */
    "outputPath":"build/",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} configuration
     * @required
     * This is configuration for your application. `Debug` should always be used unless you are submitting your app to an online
     * store - in which case `Release` should be specified.
     */
    "configuration":"Debug",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} platform
     * @required
     * This is the platform where you will be running your application. Available options are:
     *  - iOSSimulator
     *  - iOS
     *  - Android
     *  - AndroidEmulator
     */
    "platform":"AndroidEmulator",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} deviceType
     * @required
     * This is device type that your application will be running on.
     *
     * If you are developing for Android, this is not necessary.
     *
     * Available options are:
     *  - iPhone
     *  - iPad
     *  - Universal
     */
    "deviceType":"Universal",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} certificatePath
     * This is the location of your certificate.
     * This is required when you are developing for Android or you are developing on Windows.
     */
    "certificatePath":"/path/to/certificate.file",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} certificateAlias
     * This is the name of your certificate.
     *
     * IF you do not specify this on OSX, we will try and automatically find the certificate for you using the applicationId.
     *
     * This can be just a simple matcher. For example, if your  certificate name is "iPhone Developer: Robert Dougan (ABCDEFGHIJ)", you
     * can just put "iPhone Developer".
     *
     * When using a certificatePath on Windows, you do not need to specify this.
     */
    "certificateAlias":"",

    /**
     * @cfg {String} sdkPath
     * This is the path to the Android SDK, if you are developing an Android application.
     */
    "sdkPath":"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk",

    /**
     * @cfg  androidAPILevel
     * This is android API level, the version of Android SDK to use, you  can read more about it here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html.
     * Be sure to install corresponding platform API in android SDK manager (android_sdk/tools/android)
     */
    "androidAPILevel":"8",

    /**
     * @cfg  orientations
     * @required
     * This is orientations that this application can run.
     */
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

Then I run the below command on Sencha command line tool

```
sencha app build native

Code:

C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp>sencha app build native
[INFO] Deploying your application to C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp\build\package
[INFO] Copied sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Copied app.js
[INFO] Copied resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Copied resources/images
[INFO] Copied resources/icons
[INFO] Copied resources/loading
[INFO] Resolving your application dependencies...
[INFO] Found 139 dependencies. Concatenating all into app.js...
[INFO] Processed sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minifying sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Processed app.js
[INFO] Minifying app.js
[INFO] Minifying resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Minified sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minified app.js
[INFO] Minified resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Generated app.json
[INFO] Embedded microloader into index.html
[INFO] Packaging your application as a native app...

C:\path\to\www\mysenchaapp
```

Here now I am trying to run this app on android emulator, I have created a Android application in the Eclipse. I am not able to do so.

I would like to know how to add my Sencha app to this Android to run it on emulator?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is correct only if u want to run sencha app in android emulator in eclipse and u have no objection with phone gap.

if you are using eclipse to create native android applications then its really simple to run sencha application in your android emulator.

i can show u some simple steps of doing it.

1)I would suggest you to use MDS applaud phone gap http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap%20Eclipse%20PlugIn%20for%20Android
to install phonegap as u may need it at any instant.

2)As soon as u complete the installation u will see the phone gap icon at the top.

3)the click on it to create a minimal phone gap project.

4)u will then see the index file with non necessary things.
u can replace the index file as below

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
        <head>
        <title>The Sencha Touch List Component</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css">

       <script type="text/javascript" src="touch/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       Ext.Loader.setConfig({
       enabled: true,
       paths: { 'Ext': 'touch/src' }
       });
      </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body></body>
      </html>
```

5)then in the assets folder u can create the folders necessary to create a sencha application.like  the app folder,the styles folder,the touch folder and the other necessary things like the css files and the app.js.

6)U can check the configuration is correct or not by just checking out the index.html file in the web browser in eclipse only.

7)if its ok ,then u can run the application in ur android emulator,the same way as u do for ur native apps. 
And if u want to do it ur way follow this link http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video/native-apis-from-touch

Answer (score 0):

Change your platform to "Android" in the packager.json.

"AndroidEmulator" does NOT work.

I beat my head against the wall twice on this one!